# How do I override webpack chunk URL in runtime?

Tags: webpack

Ideally the function `webpackJsonp` would load a chunk from where it intends to.

I would like to make that request to `some-script.php?asset=[asset-name]`.

Is it possible to override the default webpackJsonp or somehow intercept and update the request URL?

I've tried with `publicPath`, `filename`, `chunkFilename`. Apparently they only works at build time.

[PS. I have `.js.br` and `.js.gz` files in server but webpack only loads `.js`]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `publicPath` to `some-script.php?asset=` directly does just that. The asset name gets appended at the end of it.

For cache busting I've used `some-script.php?ver=[contenthash]&asset=`.

Works just as I wanted it to.